# How to achieve full-column-length coloured background for a single line?

Tags: titles, wrapfigure, backgrounds, wrap

I'm trying to recreate a template that is currently available in MS word format. It requires me to set the journal name on top of the title. Since I'm no expert, instead of trying to write a class file, I'm modifying the tex file to achieve this.
I need to set the journal name on top of the title and the background colour of the full line should be set to black. This is what I have to achieve:

[image: Existing Template]

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Libre}[
    SizeFeatures={Size=12}
]
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 16pt

\begin{document}

\title{%
\colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\textsl{Khulna University Studies}}}}\\
\myfont Original Article
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Figures/logo.png}
\end{center}

\colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\textit{Copyright©Khulna University}}}}
\break

\myfont Here Goes The Title
}


\author{Author Name}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}
\maketitle
\hrulefill
```

And, this is what I got:

[image: Got so far]

Now, two issues:

1. How to get **full-length background** for a text line?
2. If possible, can I get the "original article" to **wrap** around the logo?

I tried the wraptext package but it mess up the entire structure. Furthermore, the `\textbf`, `\textsl`, and `\textit` are causing texts to get bigger than 12pt, which is weird. I'm compiling it with **LuaLatex** to use the `\usepackage{fontspec}` package and setting the fond to "Garamond".

Comment: What do you mean exactly with  the ‘original article’ wrapping around the logo?

Comment: @Bernard There is a text "Original Article" just beside the logo in the original word file. Check the first image for reference. I was able to put it on top of the logo (see second figure). But this should go on the left side. I couldn't wrap this single line around the logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.
The template uses a `\parbox` inside the `\colorbox` to achieve a width equal to  `\textwidth`.

[image: fx]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\title{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\normalsize{\raggedright\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}% 
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\textcolor{white}{\hfill\KUS \hfill}}}   \\[1ex]
\parbox{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-0.5\wlogo}{\oriart}%
\parbox{\wlogo}{\LOGO}\\[1ex]
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\textcolor{white}{\hfill\KUni\hfill}}}\\[3ex]
            }\titleofArt
}

\newlength{\wlogo}

% ****************************** data to be filled by the user <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\author{Author Name}
\date{} 
\newcommand{\KUS}{\small\bfseries\itshape Khulna University Studies}
\newcommand{\KUni}{\small\bfseries\itshape Copyright\/©Khulna University}
\newcommand{\oriart}{\small\bfseries ORIGINAL ARTICLE}
\setlength{\wlogo}{1.5cm}
\newcommand{\LOGO}{\includegraphics[width=\wlogo]{example-image-10x16}}
\newcommand{\titleofArt}{\Large Here Goes The Title}
% ******************************

\begin{document}
    \maketitle  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You Simon. Works like a charm.

Comment: Thank You Simon. Works like a charm.

Comment: @AtanuCSE I updated the code. Please use this version. You can change `\fboxsep` (now 4pt) to expand vertically the black lines. Their length will not change.